# Tracking down Valgrind 40 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record

Tags: c++, valgrind

I am new to Valgrind (and my C/C++ is rusty) and I am getting an error:

```
40 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 35 of 111
==26930==    at 0x4C275C2: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:261)
==26930==    by 0x5EFAFDB: cassie_init_with_timeout (cassie.cc:49)
==26930==    by 0x46E647: ngx_cassandra_upstream_get_peer (ngx_cassandra_upstream.c:274)
==26930==    by 0x41E00B: ngx_event_connect_peer (ngx_event_connect.c:25)
```

I am guessing that the char *last_error_string is giving me fits, but how do I track this down?

Here is my source:

Creation of the Cassie object:

```
cassie_t cassie;

char *error = NULL;
cassie = new Cassie(host,port,error,CASSIE_ERROR_NONE);  /* this is line 49 in the above valgrind trace */
cassie->cassandra               = cassandra;
```

cassie_t is a struct of an Object.

```
typedef struct Cassie *cassie_t;
```

I have this because I am wrapping a C++ lib in order to call it from C.

Here is our object cassie_private.h

```
#include <string>
#include "libcassandra/cassandra.h"
#include "libcassie/cassie.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
namespace libcassie {
    using namespace std;
    using namespace boost;
    class Cassie
    {
      // TODO do we need the host and the port??
      public:
            const char*     host;
        int             port;
        cassie_error_code_t last_error_code;
        char*           last_error_string; /* I am guessing my memory problem is here */
        tr1::shared_ptr<libcassandra::Cassandra>                    cassandra;

        Cassie();
        Cassie(const char *&host, int &port,char* &in_error_str, cassie_error_code_t error);
        ~Cassie();
    };
#else
    typedef
         struct Cassie
           Cassie; /* this is for in C */
#endif

}

#endif
```

Here is cassie_private.cc

```
#include "cassie_private.h"

namespace libcassie {

using namespace std;
using namespace libcassandra;

Cassie::Cassie() :
    host(),
    port(0),
    last_error_code(),
    last_error_string(NULL),
    cassandra()
{}

Cassie::Cassie(const char * &in_host, int &in_port, char* &in_error_str, cassie_error_code_t error) :
        host(in_host),
        port(in_port),
        last_error_code(error),
        last_error_string(in_error_str),
        cassandra()
{}

Cassie::~Cassie() {
    if(last_error_string) delete last_error_string;
}

}
```

This is being called in order to delete the Object at the end of use:

```
void cassie_free(cassie_t cassie) {

    if(!cassie) return;
    cassie->~Cassie();
    if(cassie) delete cassie;

}
```

How do I track this memory leak down?

Comment: What is cassie.cc line 49? Valgrind seems to be thinking you're calling `new` and then not calling `delete` on said object.

Comment: @Dan: It's worse than that; the Valgrind message means that the OP is calling `new` and then discarding the pointer at some point.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Yeah, that's more correct. Though often the cause is letting a pointer leave scope or get overwritten when you no longer need it, so you should have freed it at some point. :)

Comment: The `cassie_free` function looks very suspicious.  Why are you manually calling the destructor, and then invoking `delete`?  And why the redundant check for `NULL`?  Also, hiding a pointer behind a typedef is usually considered bad practice, because it makes the resulting code so confusing to read.

Comment: As I mentioned my C/C++ is rusty as hell.  How would I not use the a typedef in this instance?  Use the Cassie struct itself?

Comment: @chrislovecnm: Something like `Cassie *cassie = new Cassie(...)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Valgrind message means that you have allocated some memory (at line 49 of cassie.cc), but you are losing/overwriting the pointer without ever invoking `delete` on it.

You should track where that pointer value goes (either in the debugger or by inspection), in order to spot where it's being lost.  You might consider putting a debugger watchpoint on the pointer; this would identify the problem in the scenario where it's being overwritten.  If you're going to do this in the debugger, make sure you've compiled with no optimisations enabled.

Comment: How can I isolate which pointer valgrind is bitching about? Is it the char* error?

Comment: @chrislovecnm: It tells you to look at line 49 of cassie.cc.  Follow the value that `new` returns on that line.

Comment: Sorry if I am being dense. But specifically the pointer to cassie_t, not pointer inside of the struck.

Comment: @chrislovecnm: I'm not sure what you mean.  From your code snippet, I can now see that you're assigning the result of `new` to a pointer called `cassie`.  Where does it go next?

Comment: I think I need to clean up the code w/o the typedef, and track it from there.  This is some open source code that was not externed into C code well.